# I need to add a custom tab in catalog edit page of admin and need to display a custom grid collection under the tab in magento2.1.1 version

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent, tabs, magento-2.1.1, ui-form

I need to add a custom tab in catalog edit page of admin and need to display a custom grid collection under the tab.

Please find my code below:

> catalog_product_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_form">
            <block class="Test\Demo\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Demo" name="demo.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Demo Tab</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Test/Demo/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Demo

```
<?php
namespace Test\Demo\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'product/edit/demo.phtml';

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve product
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }

}
```

> product/edit/demo.phtml

```
<?php

echo 'Test contents of new tab';

?>
```

Here I am able to display content in the `demo.phtml`.

But I need to load a custom grid with its actions like filter, serach etc.

How can I load a custom admin grid in the new custom tab created in admin catalog edit page?

Answer (score 1):

To add tab use below code

create `vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customertab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

create file   **Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;

/**
 * Class Customertab
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Customertab extends AbstractModifier
{
    const DATA_SCOPE = '';
    const DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER = 'related';       
    const GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB = 'customertab';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $sortOrder = 90;

    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ProductLinkRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productLinkRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var ImageHelper
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @var Status
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $attributeSetRepository;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopeName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopePrefix;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price
     */
    private $priceModifier;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param ImageHelper $imageHelper
     * @param Status $status
     * @param AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository
     * @param string $scopeName
     * @param string $scopePrefix
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ImageHelper $imageHelper,
        Status $status,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository,
        $scopeName = '',
        $scopePrefix = ''
    ) { 
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->productLinkRepository = $productLinkRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->attributeSetRepository = $attributeSetRepository;
        $this->scopeName = $scopeName;
        $this->scopePrefix = $scopePrefix;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    { 
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                static::GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB => [
                    'children' => [
                        $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER => $this->getCustomerFieldset(),
                    ],
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Customer'),
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => static::DATA_SCOPE,
                                'sortOrder' =>
                                    $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                                        $meta,
                                        self::$previousGroup,
                                        self::$sortOrder
                                    ),
                            ],
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $productId = $product->getId();

        if (!$productId) {
            return $data;
        }

        $priceModifier = $this->getPriceModifier();
        /**
         * Set field name for modifier
         */
        $priceModifier->setData('name', 'price');

        foreach ($this->getDataScopes() as $dataScope) {
            $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope] = [];
            foreach ($this->productLinkRepository->getList($product) as $linkItem) {
                if ($linkItem->getLinkType() !== $dataScope) {
                    continue;
                }

                /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $linkedProduct */
                $linkedProduct = $this->productRepository->get(
                    $linkItem->getLinkedProductSku(),
                    false,
                    $this->locator->getStore()->getId()
                );
                $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope][] = $this->fillData($linkedProduct, $linkItem);
            }
            if (!empty($data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope])) {
                $dataMap = $priceModifier->prepareDataSource([
                    'data' => [
                        'items' => $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope]
                    ]
                ]);
                $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope] = $dataMap['data']['items'];
            }
        }

        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_product_id'] = $productId;
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_store_id'] = $this->locator->getStore()->getId();

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get price modifier
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getPriceModifier()
    {
        if (!$this->priceModifier) {
            $this->priceModifier = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price::class
            );
        }
        return $this->priceModifier;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data column
     *
     * @param ProductInterface $linkedProduct
     * @param ProductLinkInterface $linkItem
     * @return array
     */
    protected function fillData(ProductInterface $linkedProduct, ProductLinkInterface $linkItem)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $linkedProduct->getId(),
            'thumbnail' => $this->imageHelper->init($linkedProduct, 'product_listing_thumbnail')->getUrl(),
            'name' => $linkedProduct->getName(),
            'status' => $this->status->getOptionText($linkedProduct->getStatus()),
            'attribute_set' => $this->attributeSetRepository
                ->get($linkedProduct->getAttributeSetId())
                ->getAttributeSetName(),
            'sku' => $linkItem->getLinkedProductSku(),
            'price' => $linkedProduct->getPrice(),
            'position' => $linkItem->getPosition(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all data scopes
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getDataScopes()
    {
        return [
            static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepares config for the Related products fieldset
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCustomerFieldset()
    {
        $content = __(
            'Related products are shown to customers in addition to the item the customer is looking at.'
        );

        return [
            'children' => [
                'button_set' => $this->getButtonSet(
                    $content,
                    __('Add Related Products'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER
                ),
                'modal' => $this->getGenericModal(
                    __('Add Related Products'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER
                ),
                static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER => $this->getGrid($this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER),
            ],
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__fieldset-section',
                        'label' => __('Customer'),
                        'collapsible' => false,
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve button set
     *
     * @param Phrase $content
     * @param Phrase $buttonTitle
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getButtonSet(Phrase $content, Phrase $buttonTitle, $scope)
    {
        $modalTarget = $this->scopeName . '.' . static::GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB . '.' . $scope . '.modal';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'formElement' => 'container',
                        'componentType' => 'container',
                        'label' => false,
                        'content' => $content,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'button_' . $scope => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement' => 'container',
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                'actions' => [
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget,
                                        'actionName' => 'toggleModal',
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget . '.' . $scope . '_product_listing',
                                        'actionName' => 'render',
                                    ]
                                ],
                                'title' => $buttonTitle,
                                'provider' => null,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepares config for modal slide-out panel
     *
     * @param Phrase $title
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getGenericModal(Phrase $title, $scope)
    {
        $listingTarget = $scope . '_product_listing';

        $modal = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'options' => [
                            'title' => $title,
                            'buttons' => [
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Cancel'),
                                    'actions' => [
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Add Selected Products'),
                                    'class' => 'action-primary',
                                    'actions' => [
                                        [
                                            'targetName' => 'index = ' . $listingTarget,
                                            'actionName' => 'save'
                                        ],
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                $listingTarget => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'autoRender' => false,
                                'componentType' => 'insertListing',
                                'dataScope' => $listingTarget,
                                'externalProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '_data_source',
                                'selectionsProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '.product_columns.ids',
                                'ns' => $listingTarget,
                                'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render'),
                                'realTimeLink' => true,
                                'dataLinks' => [
                                    'imports' => false,
                                    'exports' => true
                                ],
                                'behaviourType' => 'simple',
                                'externalFilterMode' => true,
                                'imports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_store_id',
                                ],
                                'exports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_store_id',
                                ]
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $modal;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve grid
     *
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function getGrid($scope)
    {
        $dataProvider = $scope . '_product_listing';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                        'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                        'label' => null,
                        'columnsHeader' => false,
                        'columnsHeaderAfterRender' => true,
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'template' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/templates/grid',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid',
                        'addButton' => false,
                        'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                        'dataScope' => 'data.links',
                        'deleteButtonLabel' => __('Remove'),
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'map' => [
                            'id' => 'entity_id',
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'status' => 'status_text',
                            'attribute_set' => 'attribute_set_text',
                            'sku' => 'sku',
                            'price' => 'price',
                            'thumbnail' => 'thumbnail_src',
                        ],
                        'links' => [
                            'insertData' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }'
                        ],
                        'sortOrder' => 2,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'dataScope' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => $this->fillMeta(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve meta column
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function fillMeta()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getTextColumn('id', false, __('ID'), 0),
            'thumbnail' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/thumbnail',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'thumbnail',
                            'fit' => true,
                            'label' => __('Thumbnail'),
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'name' => $this->getTextColumn('name', false, __('Name'), 20),
            'status' => $this->getTextColumn('status', true, __('Status'), 30),
            'attribute_set' => $this->getTextColumn('attribute_set', false, __('Attribute Set'), 40),
            'sku' => $this->getTextColumn('sku', true, __('SKU'), 50),
            'price' => $this->getTextColumn('price', true, __('Price'), 60),
            'actionDelete' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'additionalClasses' => 'data-grid-actions-cell',
                            'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'label' => __('Actions'),
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'fit' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'position' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'position',
                            'sortOrder' => 80,
                            'visible' => false,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text column structure
     *
     * @param string $dataScope
     * @param bool $fit
     * @param Phrase $label
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTextColumn($dataScope, $fit, Phrase $label, $sortOrder)
    {
        $column = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/text',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/text',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => $dataScope,
                        'fit' => $fit,
                        'label' => $label,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $column;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used your code to add a new tab in admin product edit page.But I am unable to find a new tab.
Did we need to edit anything or add more files/code to make it display in product edit page?

Comment: Add di.xml to vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Comment: Thanks for your code.A new tab is added.

While clicking on Add Related Products button,no grid is loaded and showing an error 'Something went wrong.'

My requirement is to add a custom grid in the slide screen opened on clicking  Add Related Products button.

Also where the remove action code can be added in the grid shown after selecting and saving the custom grid data.

Let me know how the custom grid is added and where the actions in grid is written.

Comment: @santoshp i have updated answer that will solve error of something went wrong